# How to choose seeds for two random number generators so that sequences would be completely uncorrelated?

Tags: random

I want to use rejection sampling to generate random numbers from a given distribution. I want to be quite general so that I don't want to relay on things like Box-Muller transformation which can generate only normal distributed random numbers. I am using linear congruential generator to generate a random sequence between 0 and 1 with uniform distribution. To use rejection sampling, I need to generate two sequences of random numbers so that I would be able to generate uniform points inside a 2d region. This can be done using two random sequences (one for x coordinate and other for y coordinate). I searched on Internet but nowhere I saw how to make sure that these two sequences are really uncorrelated. Is there any way to choose seeds for these such that these sequences are uncorrelated? If I randomly give seeds then the final distribution of these numbers is not quite like what I am looking for.

Thank you

Comment: How about using the same random sequence genrator for both coordinates?

Comment: That will span only line x=y. I want these points fill the region of xy plane uniformly.

Comment: They will, and using 2 sequenves instead of one won't make any difference because the function is the same no matter what seed was used. But they are random, so you they will only look like uniform agter s lot of samples.

Comment: I am really not getting you. If I use the same seed then how would I be able to use rejection method because I am not then generating random points uniformly in 2d

Comment: x1 = random.next, y1 = random.next, x2 = random. next, y2 = random.next

Comment: Oh.. will that fill the whole region ? Intuitively it seems that it will not.. but let me give try to this..

Comment: try like some thousands points